# emacs function for switching between header and implementation for non-standard project structure

Tags: c++, emacs, elisp

I'm working on a C++ project with a bit uncommon layout of source and include files (well, at least it's uncommon for what I've seen so far) and am trying to come up with a helper emacs function for switching between .cpp and respective .h file (for this particular case only, so it doesn't need to be super flexible), because ff-find-other-file fails on this setup. This is also an elisp learning experience for me.

The project structure is set up as follows:

- source files fall within projectname/src/namespacepath/*.cpp
- respective include files fall withing projectname/include/namespacepath/*.h

In addition I may have an additional checkout of that project (projectname2/....) and switching between cpp and h should happen within project boundaries.

In other words, for a source file Foo.cpp of class Foo in namespace a::b::c I have:

- project/src/a/b/c/Foo.cpp
- project/include/a/b/c/Foo.h

The "project" itself is kept in a "src" directory where I keep all my sources (so the full path is something like ~/src/project/src/....), which means the function should only replace "src" with "include" for the last "src" occurence in the path.

I came up with the below elisp function; it substitues the last occurence of "src" with "include" in the current file path and "cpp" extension with "h" (or vice versa) and tries to visit the resulting file.

Since I'm new to lisp, I'd be interested in knowing if it can be made any simpler? Or perhaps ff-find-other-file can be customized to do exactly this? (and yeah, I've seen ff-search-directories, but that wouldn't help when working on multiple checkouts of the same project).

```
(defun alternate-include-or-src()
  (interactive)
  (let (
        (name)
        (newname "")
        (repl t)
        )
    (setq name (nreverse (split-string (buffer-file-name) "/")))
    (setq filename (car name))
    (dolist (p (cdr name)) ;; iterate over reversed list of path components
      (if repl   ;; do the src <-> substitution only once
          (if (string= p "src")
              (progn
                (setq p "include"
                      repl nil)
                (setq filename (concat (file-name-sans-extension filename) ".h"))
                )                       
            (if (string= p "include")
                (progn
                  (setq p "src"
                        repl nil)
                  (setq filename (concat (file-name-sans-extension filename) ".cpp"))
                  )
              )                         
            )
        )
      (setq newname (concat p "/" newname))
      )
    (setq newname (concat newname filename))
    (if (file-exists-p newname)
        (find-file newname)
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: I suggest using CEDET `semantic-ia-fast-jump`. It should work for almost all includes once you configure
it properly. And `semanic-symref` is not bad to go the other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to have a look into `cc-other-file-alist`, for its use with `ff-find-other-file`.  It allows custom function calls and you can save some coding:

Example:

```
(setq cc-other-file-alist
  `(
    ("\\.cxx$" ,(my-look-for-other-file-1))
    ("\\.hxx$" ,(my-look-for-other-file-2))))
```

Comment: Thanks, almost got it working that way: I slightly modifed my alternate-include-or-src function to take filename argument and return nil for paths that don't match expected directory structure and Ive set up cc-other-file-alist to call my function for .cpp and .h. However, now I have an issue for any other project, ff-find-other-file doesn't work anymore for typical use cases. How can I make this configuration fall back to a default behavior?

Comment: My suggestion would be to add a hook to c-mode-common-hook that makes cc-other-file-alist buffer local, and assign that value to it, when your path matches the path of your "special" projects.